# How do I link a chtml file to a Javascript file in .NET Core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-core

So I'm wanting to create a simple dropdown list using Javascript . So I'm just wondering how do I link up the chtml file containing the structure to the right Javascript file in .NET Core 8. I'm using the webapp MVC template.

There is the wwwroot folder containing the Javascript file but I'm just not sure how to link that up with my page.

I know there is the _Layout file that contains the stylesheets and Js & Jquery links but I'm not sure how to link them up

I've tried creating a normal dropdown with @Html but it does not suit my use case.

Here is the Home Index file that I'm working with

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}



<div class="text-center">

    <label class="form-label" >Role</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Role", 
    Html.GetEnumSelectList<ERoles>(), "Select Role", 
    new { @class = "form-control"})



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put a js refrence at the end of cshtml. Such as in the "Index.cshtml":

```
...
<script src="~/js/test.js" />
```

[image]